# Form all possible unique sums and all ways to compute them by choosing and adding elements from two arrays

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

Given two arrays A and B of size n and m respectively. We can choose an element from A and one from B such that C=Ai + Bj . We have to compute all possible ways to from a sum C and also all unique sums.

Constraints:-

`0<A,B<=10^5` // Size of array A and B

`0<=Ai,Bi<=10^6`

Sample I/P:-

2 3 //Size of array A and B

5 6 // Elements of array A

2 2 3 //Elements of array B

Sample O/P:-

7 2

8 3

9 1

Explanation:- 7 can be formed in two ways by A1+B1 , A1+B2 (using 1-based indexing)

8 can be formed in 3 ways by A1+B2 , A2+B1 , A2+B2

9 can be formed in 1 way by A2+B3

Please help me with a solution less than (n*m).

Here is my code:-

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,m,val;
    cin>>n>>m;
    unordered_map<int,int> A;
    unordered_map<int,int> B;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>val;
        A[val]++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        cin>>val;
        B[val]++;
    }
    map<int,int> ans;
    for(auto it=A.begin();it!=A.end();it++)
    {
        for(auto it1=B.begin();it1!=B.end();it1++)
        {
            ans[it->first+it1->first]+= it->second*it1->second;
        }
    }
    for(auto it=ans.begin();it!=ans.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a way? because counting all recurrence of the sum seem to be n*m

Comment: Yes there is a way for sure, because this question was asked in an exam . Time limit given is 2-4 secs for C++.

Comment: And you tested times for `m*n`? Consider case where all sum are different- only output the result will be `m*n`

Comment: `n*m` unique sums: `A = [1, 2, 3]`, `B = [10, 20, 30]`.

Comment: I am looking for a complexity of less than O(n*m) , because n*m gave me a TLE.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I have provided it.